# How to use terminal while coding in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I have a few php files open in **Vim**, at the same time I want to **list** files from specific **folder** in the same **server** in terminal. How should I do that ?

For example:

In **terminal**, I am in **devserver:~$**

Using **Vim**, I have opened few files to continue my work.

Now, to do other operations on the same server (for example, I would like to **list** files from **styles/**),  how do I use the terminal window/tab ?

**What I do**:

In one tab, open files using **Vim** and 
In another tab do other operations in same **server** (like **listing/removing** etc).

In this case, I have to do **ssh** login for each tab. 
Is there any way where I can code using **Vim** and do other operations in the same 
**server** in **terminal** ?

Please guide me for the **best practices** for this.

Comment: one time you need to do `ssh` in new tab and it's not costly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> to suspend `vim`, and <kbd>fg</kbd> to call it back.

---

If you want to do 3+ tasks at the same time, I suggest `tmux`.

Comment: Also, if you use tmux and the plugin vim-gtfo the "got" command will open the terminal in a tmux window side by side with Vim, pretty nifty.

Answer (score 7):

In command mode you can use `!<command>`

For example:

```
:!ls
```

to list files in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

Use `tmux` (or `screen`).  It will allow you to have multiple shells open via the one ssh connection.  If for some reason you don't want to use a terminal emulator (although you get so many benefits from doing so that I can't imagine why you wouldn't want to.  For example, if your ssh session is terminated for any reason, your vim session will stay active and you can reattach to it), you can shell out from vim with:

```
:!ls styles
```

Answer (score 3):

You can launch a shell with `:!bash` and get back to vim when you exit

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using "shell" command

```
:shell
```

Or you can also manage files in Vim using plugins like NERDTree. https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives to using `<c-z>` and `:!ls`:

- `<c-x><c-f>` in insert completes filenames
- `:sp styles` open the directory with netrw. Netrw is Vim's file explorer
- Better yet forget the split, `:e styles` then `<c-6>` to get back. Use `:Rex` to restore explorer

For more help see:

```
:h ctrl-z
:h :!
:h i_ctrl-x_ctrl-f
:h :Explore
:h :Rex
```